# Svelte script context='module' variables changes but no update on view

Tags: svelte

Why  is not updating?
here an simple example

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/23ca272a94bd48c6b6d2a1a4a77f10a8?version=3.23.2)

TreeView does not update with tree_two value. How can the tree_two updated to TreeView component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables in `context='module'` are not reactive and the component instances will receive the *current* value when mounting.

In order to have a reactive variable shared over all the instances you can simply make it a store:

```html
<script context="module">
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store
    const _expansionState = writable({})
</script>
```

Comment: Don't  understand. I added your code but still same result https://svelte.dev/repl/4769669518b04123a45dcda5e82644ef?version=3.37.0

or do I need to export _expansionState and import it in App.svelte?

Comment: Your problem is that you do `const { label, children } = tree` this will initialize label and children to the values of tree when the component is being instantiated.  When values change the code in the script block is not re-executed like in other frameworks. Thus even with a new tree, label and children remain the same, to tell Svelte to update label when tree changes you have to mark it as reactive: `$: label = tree.label` (same for children)